# Как проверить наличие класса

Tags: jquery

В процессе выполнения кода divу присваеваеться класс как проверить его и если он приствоен класс и если присвоен то выполнить действие

html до кода

```
<div class="one"></div>
```

после кода

```
<div class="one two"></div>
```

код на проверку присвоение класса вот

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if $('.two').(function(e){
             alert(ok);}
```

я понмаю что не туплю я понмаю что низнаю jquery но я ни знаю ни где посмотреть ни где это можно зучить подскажите пожалуста как это решить. 
Пожалуста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встроенной функции или callback'a для addClass не существует. Можно правда переписать функция addClass() и добавить callback. Но проще и лучше поступить следующим образом:

```
// в нужный момент добавляем класс
$('.one').addClass('two');
// используем кастомное событие, которое сигнализирует о том что класс поменяли
$(document).trigger('cssClassChanged');

$(document).on('cssClassChanged', function(){ 
     //класс поменялся обрабатываем его т.е
});
```

Comment: Тот кто поставил минус, пусть обоснует за что. В задаче класс присваивается динамически и простой проверкой hasClass тут не обойтись.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(".one").hasClass('two')) ....
```